# Преобразовать lat/lng в GeoPoint

Tags: java, android, kotlin, openstreetmap

Всем привет! Снова прошу совет. В приложении получаю координаты маршрута в виде закодированной полилинии. Раскодирую их следующим образом:

```
var route = PolyUtil.decode(arrRoutes[index])
```

В итоге получаю строку вида:

> lat/lng: (55.82182,49.146060000000006)

Как я могу её изменить в вид GeoPoint для построения полилинии в osmdroid?

Answer (score 0):

Ну GeoPoint это объект который должен содержать поля для хранения lat/lng.

Вы можете создать свой объект GeoPoint и положить в него эти параметры с помощью методов `setLat()`, `setLng()` (методы могут иметь немного другой нейминг). Может быть вариант, что эти параметры передаются через конструктор.

Если вы получаете их строкой и вас интересует как вам их разбить? 
То тут вам поможет мтеод `Str.split(",")`. Вы получите на выходе массив из двух строк, которые вы сможете преобразовать в `long` с помощью этого метода `Long.valueOf()`